# can't get numpy.transpose to operate on what outwardly seems to be an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, transpose

The following code takes a list of lists arranged as 3 rows of 14 columns and converts it to an array. However, the application of numpy.flip and numpy.transpose appears to do nothing to the new array, although the shape is recognized...is this somehow not properly formatted as a 3x14 array in spite of what 'shape' says?

```
fitarray = numpy.array(listoflists)

print 'original'
print fitarray
print 'shape:', fitarray.shape

#reverse order in array
numpy.flipud(numpy.fliplr(fitarray))

print 'after flipping'
print fitarray
print 'shape:' fitarray.shape

numpy.transpose(fitarray)

print 'after transpose'
print fitarray
print 'shape:' fitarray.shape
```

Here is the output from the above code:

original

```
[[ 1.          1.          0.75922332  0.72510804  0.60655371  0.61518896
   0.43338281  0.31000672  0.36051202  0.29079866  0.28775219  0.41336631
   0.53799258  0.52036007]
 [ 0.46761031  0.9629559   1.          1.          1.          1.
   0.95181012  0.90766551  0.88126941  0.88357832  0.90511121  0.95506566
   0.99609776  1.        ]
 [ 0.55385467  0.91574368  0.78931241  0.83173184  0.87563584  0.9592057
   1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
   0.99809394]]

shape: (3, 14)
```

after flipping

```
[[ 1.          1.          0.75922332  0.72510804  0.60655371  0.61518896
   0.43338281  0.31000672  0.36051202  0.29079866  0.28775219  0.41336631
   0.53799258  0.52036007]
 [ 0.46761031  0.9629559   1.          1.          1.          1.
   0.95181012  0.90766551  0.88126941  0.88357832  0.90511121  0.95506566
   0.99609776  1.        ]
 [ 0.55385467  0.91574368  0.78931241  0.83173184  0.87563584  0.9592057
   1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
   0.99809394]]

shape: (3, 14)
```

after transpose

```
[[ 1.          1.          0.75922332  0.72510804  0.60655371  0.61518896
   0.43338281  0.31000672  0.36051202  0.29079866  0.28775219  0.41336631
   0.53799258  0.52036007]
 [ 0.46761031  0.9629559   1.          1.          1.          1.
   0.95181012  0.90766551  0.88126941  0.88357832  0.90511121  0.95506566
   0.99609776  1.        ]
 [ 0.55385467  0.91574368  0.78931241  0.83173184  0.87563584  0.9592057
   1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
   0.99809394]]

shape: (3, 14)
```

Comment: Errr. don't you need to assign the result of the np operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the operations as per the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html)

example:

```
In [182]:

a = np.random.randn(3*14).reshape(3,14)
a
Out[182]:
array([[-1.09047556, -0.03717911,  1.56770073, -0.44577998,  1.89357885,
        -0.53837911,  0.74492976,  0.55248619,  1.19553176, -0.90725472,
         1.33540847, -0.36895309, -0.1392841 ,  0.21324307],
       [ 0.95891412,  0.0810524 , -0.29181996,  0.2275121 ,  1.06491463,
        -0.94156398,  0.04786322,  0.15859003,  0.06085846, -0.8113653 ,
        -0.64495641,  0.03964511, -0.36936448, -1.21301754],
       [-0.1486475 ,  0.61538289, -0.42302942,  0.46333247,  1.65154601,
        -0.16310981,  0.09809179, -0.37837943,  0.98993927,  0.1095821 ,
        -0.69703357, -0.62647274,  1.05738354,  0.01542917]])

In [185]:

b = np.transpose(a)
print(a.shape, b.shape)
(3, 14) (14, 3)

In [189]:

a_copy = a.copy()
b = np.flipud(np.fliplr(a))
print((a_copy == a).all())
print((b == a).all())
True
False
```